# Passing additional data with governance proposal

Tags: solidity, governance, dynamic-call

I'm creating a governor which handles multiple choice voting.  My issue is how I can leverage the results in the contracts.

My initial thought was to dynamically inject the results at the end of the calldata, but do to the poor layout of encoding, I cannot just append calldata.

After investigating the layout of general governance I have an execute method which looks like so:

```
function execute(uint256 proposalId) public payable virtual override returns (uint256) {
    ProposalCore storage proposal = _proposals[proposalId];
    ProposalState status = state(proposalId);
    require(
        status == ProposalState.Succeeded || status == ProposalState.Queued,
        "MG: proposal not successful"
    );
    proposal.executed = true;

    emit ProposalExecuted(proposalId);
    
    _beforeExecute(proposal);
    _execute(proposal);
    _afterExecute(proposal);

    return proposalId;
}
```

I'm thinking it might be feasible to inject the data beforeExecution by checking if the target address Implements an interface, and if so then calling a function on the contract before execution and storing the values inside.

Does anyone have a better idea or pattern for handling dynamic execution?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help but i'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "My issue is how I can leverage the results in the contracts." ? Can you give more details of what problem do you want to solve?

Comment: When you create a governance proposal, you create the method and the calldata ahead of time before execution.  

I need to pass the results of my proposal to any of the targets which require the results

Comment: See if this doesn't help you: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/governance#:~:text=Governor,Governor%20contract%20using%20Contracts%20Wizard.

Comment: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard

Comment: No, this is a custom governor